# Why does nothing happen when I click on a link that calls this function?

Tags: php, javascript

It's not a syntactic issue as best as I can tell (other JS function calls work just fine on the very same page).

The very first question it asks is if a particular DIV id has its display property set to "none" (it does), and, if so, it should set it to "block" (along with a few others things), but absolutely nothing happens. I wrote the function for a different site, and it was working just fine there, and now ... nothing. I'm pulling my hair out! Thanks in advance...

```
        function showHideFooter(FooterLinkP,FooterLinkSPAN)
        {   
            var DIV = document.getElementById('FooterLinksContentDIV');
            var P = document.getElementById(FooterLinkP);
            var SPAN = document.getElementById(FooterLinkSPAN);

            if (DIV.style.display == 'none')
            {
                DIV.style.display = 'block';
                P.style.display = 'block';
                SPAN.style.border = '1px solid #606060;';
                SPAN.setAttribute('style','background: url("img/navlinkhoverbg.jpg")');
            }
            else if ((DIV.style.display == 'block') && (SPAN.style.border !== 'transparent'))
            {
                P.style.display = 'none';
                DIV.style.display = 'none';
                SPAN.style.background = 'transparent';
                SPAN.style.border = 'transparent';
                SPAN.setAttribute('style','background:hover:url("img/navlinkhoverbg.jpg")');
                SPAN.setAttribute('style','border:hover: 1px solid #606060;');
            }
            else
            {
                var number = 1;

                var contentArray = new Array();
                contentArray[0] = '<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(1,'title');?>';
                contentArray[1] = '<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(2,'title');?>';         
                contentArray[2] = '<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(3,'title');?>';
                contentArray[3] = '<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(4,'title');?>';
                contentArray[4] = '<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(5,'title');?>';
                contentArray[5] = '<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(6,'title');?>';
                contentArray[6] = '<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(7,'title');?>';
                contentArray[7] = '<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(8,'title');?>';
                contentArray[8] = '<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(9,'title');?>';

                for (section in contentArray)
                {
                    document.getElementById(contentArray[section]).style.display = 'none';

                    while (number <= 9)
                    {
                        document.getElementById(number).style.background = 'transparent';
                        document.getElementById(number).style.border = 'transparent';
                        document.getElementById(number).setAttribute('style','background:hover:url("img/navlinkhoverbg.jpg")');
                        document.getElementById(number).setAttribute('style','border:hover: 1px solid #606060;');
                        number++;
                    }   
                }
                P.style.display = 'block';
                SPAN.style.border = '1px solid #606060;';
                SPAN.setAttribute('style','background:url("img/navlinkhoverbg.jpg")');
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<SPAN class="FooterLinkSPAN" id="1">
<A href="#links" onclick="showHideFooter('<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(1,'title'); ?>','1');" class="footerLinks"><? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(1,'title');?></A>
</SPAN>
```

An alert placed in the if and else if statements yields nothing, but placed in the else statement pops up, so it's considering the first two chunks to be false ... but they're not. I don't get it. But you guys answer quick! This site is great!

Comment: Does the debugger tell you anything? Also, please post "link" markup/code.

Comment: It might be helpful if you show us your html as well. You have set up the call for the javascript wrong and the function therefore would not be called.

Comment: Walk through the code with a proper debugger. In 2012, there's [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) for not using one. You can know *exactly* what the code is doing, set breakpoints, inspect variables, etc., etc., on all major browsers. It's almost a secret how powerful the tools built into browsers are these days. :-)

Comment: <SPAN class="FooterLinkSPAN" id="1"><A href="#links" onclick="showHideFooter('<? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(1,'title'); ?>','1');" class="footerLinks"><? echo METHODS::footerPopulator(1,'title');?></A></SPAN>
An alert placed in the if and else if statements yields nothing, but placed in the else statement pops up, so it's considering the first two chunks to be false ... but they're not. I don't get it. But you guys answer quick! This site is great!

Comment: Also, what's a good, free debugger?

Comment: Open browser, hit F12. Voilà.

Comment: @MattPayne: Google Chrome has really nice tools built in. On a Mac, it's under `View > Developer`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have `display:none` set in the CSS, and not inline on the element. If it's just in CSS, the `DIV.style.display` will be `""` instead of `"none"`.

If that's the case, change the first `if()` statement to this...

```
if (!DIV.style.display || DIV.style.display == 'none')
        {
```

Comment: I'd vote that up if I could, but I can't, but thanks! Did the trick! A million thanks!